# Mostrar Notificacion con toastr.js en archivo donde sera redireccionado despues de success

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirección, notificaciones

Tengo la siguiente inquietud.
Tengo un formulario que se envia a traves de ajax y se valida antes de su envio con  formvalidation. Todo funciona bien, pero necesito que la notificacion, sea mostrada en el archivo en donde sera redireccionado despues del success de ajax.
La primera ventana de notificacion se genera a traves de SWAL y ahi pregunta si se quiere enviar o no el pedido y luego de eso, genera la notificacion con toastr. 
Este es mi codigo:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

var newDate = new Date(Date.now() + <?php echo $dia_max?>*24*60*60*1000);

$('#datePicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: 'true',
    language: 'es',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    startDate : newDate
})
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {
        $('#envia_pedidoE').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
    });
});

$('#envia_pedidoE').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    excluded: ':disabled',

    fields: {
        obs: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Ingrese Obs. de Pedido.'
                }
            }
        },
        date: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Seleccione Fecha'
                },
                date: {
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    message: 'Formato Fecha NO VALIDO'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).on('success.form.fv', function(e) {

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#envia_pedidoE').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var datos = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "envioE.php",
                data : datos,

                success:function(data){
                var href = "archivoderedireccion.php";
                swal({
                 title: "Realizará Envío de Pedido",
                 text: "Para Usuario",
                 icon: "info",
                 buttons: true,
                 dangerMode: true,
                })
               .then((envio) => {
                 if (envio) {
                  $.toast({
                  heading: 'Envío de Pedido',
                  text: 'Proceso Realizado con Exito. El Pedido Fué Enviado Correctamente.',
                  position: 'top-right',
                  loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                  icon: 'success',
                  hideAfter: 4500,
                  stack: 6
                });
                  window.location.href = href;
              } else {
                 $.toast({
                 heading: 'Envío de Pedido',
                 text: 'Se Ha Cancelado en Envío del Pedido.',
                 position: 'top-right',
                 loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                 icon: 'error',
                 hideAfter: 4500
              });
            }
            });
            $('#respuesta').html(data);
            }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Como les comentaba, lo anterior funciona pero el mensaje desarece de inmediato y lo que necesito es hacer una redireccion a archivoderedireccion.php y en ese archivo se muestre la notificacion de toastr.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo u orientarme de alguna manera, se los agradeceria mucho.
Como siempre agradecido de antemano, por su ayuda.

Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes lograrlo asi:

- Si haces una validación previa, añade en los datos a llevarte dicha validación. Con algo sencillo, tipo:

> var validation = {'success':0, 'message': 'blablabla'};

suficiente, o el mensaje lo determinas ya en la página a la cual redireccionas. Eso ya customizalo como quieras.

- En la página donde recibes los datos, pasa los datos que recibes de la validación a js, hazte una función que saque el toastr en caso de que la validación no llegue como esperas, y la invocas nada más recibir los datos:

> ```
> function showToastr(data){
>     if(!data.success){
>        toastr.warning(data.message);
>     }
> }
> showToastr(datos_recibidos.validation);
> ```

Luego, armando una función un poquito mejor puedes customizartelo como quieras: infos, warning, etc..